ModuleNotFoundError: No module named while trying a local import
This is the structure of my project

while trying to run
from database.db import engine

inside User.py I get the following error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'database'

The code editor (VS Code) seems to suggest it's structured well since IntelliSense provides method suggestions for the engine object, implying the import is being done correctly.
How to fix this without any PATH hacks and using absolute imports?
